# Freeform conditionals

Tags: plugin-freeform, checkboxes

This code works as expected...

```
{% if submission.symptomCheckerSymptoms == "Itching" %}
    it works
{% endif %}
```

... but when when multiple options are selected, it doesn't.

The field is a checkbox group. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The solution is:

```
{% if "itching" in submission.symptomCheckerSymptoms.value %}
{% endif %}
```